# model fit issue. Showing -> invalid Argument Error

Tags: model, conv-neural-network, model-fitting

```
Found 1594 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 409 images belonging to 2 classes.




r = model.fit(
    training_set,
    validation_data=test_set,
    epochs=50,
    steps_per_epoch=len(training_set),
    validation_steps=len(test_set))
```

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[50], line 1
----> 1 r = model.fit(
2     training_set,
3     validation_data=test_set,
4     epochs=50,
5 #     steps_per_epoch=len(training_set),
6     validation_steps=len(test_set))

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback..error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.**traceback**)
68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
71 finally:
72     del filtered_tb

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py:52, in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
50 try:
51   ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 52   tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
53                                       inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
54 except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
55   if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'ArgMax_1' defined at (most recent call last):
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 17, in 
app.launch_new_instance()
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 1043, in launch_instance
app.start()
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 725, in start
self.io_loop.start()
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tornado/platform/asyncio.py", line 195, in start
self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 603, in run_forever
self._run_once()
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1909, in _run_once
handle._run()
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run
self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 513, in dispatch_queue
await self.process_one()
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 502, in process_one
await dispatch(*args)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 409, in dispatch_shell
await result
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 729, in execute_request
reply_content = await reply_content
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 422, in do_execute
res = shell.run_cell(
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 540, in run_cell
return super().run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3009, in run_cell
result = self._run_cell(
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3064, in _run_cell
result = runner(coro)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py", line 129, in *pseudo_sync_runner
coro.send(None)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3269, in run_cell_async
has_raised = await self.run_ast_nodes(code_ast.body, cell_name,
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3448, in run_ast_nodes
if await self.run_code(code, result, async*=asy):
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3508, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
File "/tmp/ipykernel_28/299887100.py", line 1, in 
r = model.fit(
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
return fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1685, in fit
tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1284, in train_function
return step_function(self, iterator)

```
type here
```

```
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1268, in step_function
  outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in run_step
  outputs = model.train_step(data)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1055, in train_step
  return self.compute_metrics(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1149, in compute_metrics
  self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred, sample_weight)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 605, in update_state
  metric_obj.update_state(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=mask)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/utils/metrics_utils.py", line 77, in decorated
  update_op = update_state_fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/metrics/base_metric.py", line 140, in update_state_fn
  return ag_update_state(*args, **kwargs)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/metrics/base_metric.py", line 691, in update_state
  matches = ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/metrics/accuracy_metrics.py", line 426, in categorical_accuracy
  return metrics_utils.sparse_categorical_matches(
File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/utils/metrics_utils.py", line 965, in sparse_categorical_matches
  y_pred = tf.math.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)
```

Node: 'ArgMax_1'
Reduction axis -1 is empty in shape [32,0]
[[{{node ArgMax_1}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_84929]